Process the image to extract handwritten text for the neural network
I want to identify the squares in the image and extract the letters written in them, but I can't get the whole letter. I only get fragments like in the images shown below.
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img_path = "img.png"

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Smooth the edges to facilitate sharpening
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
# sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 5, -1], [0, -1, 0]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(blur, -1, sharpen_kernel)

# Apply adaptive thresholding to create a binary image and close gaps
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(sharpen, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)

# Detect contours and filter based on area size
contours = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
min_area = 350
max_area = 6200
image_number = 0
lower_blue = np.array([90, 50, 20])  
upper_blue = np.array([150, 255, 255]) 
# Avoid the small/big random contours that are detected
contours = filter(lambda contour: min_area < cv2.contourArea(contour) < max_area, contours)
# Sort the contours to get them as a 'line'
sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda contour: cv2.boundingRect(contour)[0])
selected_rects = []
for c in sorted_contours:
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
# Make sure that the rectangles do not overleap with the already selected ones
if not any(x > rect[0] and y > rect[1] and x + w < rect[0] + rect[2] and y + h < rect[1] + rect[3] for rect in selected_rects):
    ROI = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    ROI = cv2.GaussianBlur(ROI, (3, 3), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(ROI, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    blue_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
    # Make sure that the rectangle has blue within it to avoid random rectangles
    if blue_pixels > 100:
        binary_image = cv2.resize(mask, (28, 28))
        cv2.imwrite(f'./resources/ROI_{image_number}.png', binary_image)
        image_number += 1
        selected_rects.append((x, y, w, h))

Initial Image

Some of the extracted ROIs

Masks that are incomplete

I tried to remove the gray border and then transform all the pixels that were not white into bright blue. However, I couldn't remove all of the border in every case, and sometimes there were random yellowish spots because the image was scanned.

Perhaps thresholding on the blue characters with cv2.inRange() might work better than converting to gray and adaptive threshold.

do not do any thresholding. neural networks have no issue taking grayscale or 3-channel (color) data. your thresholding ruins the data.
